# getting rid of subqueries in a query that gets the first element in each group

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

I've got the following query to get the latest row in each group

```
SELECT s1.* FROM ps s1
JOIN (
   SELECT s2.id FROM ps s2
   WHERE s2.userId = 63
   ORDER BY s2.date DESC
) as a
ON (s1.id = a.id)
GROUP BY s1.name
```

However this query is performing very poorly.
Is there an equivalent query that could get rid of the subqueries and/or any other optimization that could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `not exists`, by choosing rows where there is no larger date for a given `name`:

```
select ps.*
from ps
where not exists (select 1
                  from ps ps2
                  where ps2.name = ps.name and
                        ps2.userid = 63 and
                        ps2.date > ps.date
                 ) and
      ps.userid = 63;
```

This will work best with an index on `ps(name, userid, date)`.

Comment: i ran an explain on this query and another equivalent one.